# Action Bar Color not changing no matter what?

Tags: android

I have tried every thing on stackoverflow to change my action bar color
please help

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#b20e0f</item>
</style>
```

Comment: what's your `targetSDKversion`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your style to:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="background">@color/action_bar_bg</item>
</style>
```

Define "action_bar_bg" in res/values/colors.xml:

```
<color name="action_bar_bg">#b20e0f</color>
```

Reason: actionBarStyle is appcompat attribute. Don't use android: with it. Same for background.

Comment: Before API 3.0 no need use `android:`, but `API >= 3.0`, you need `android:`. And also you can use `#b20e0f` directly

Comment: @Xcihnegn No. Appcompat library is being used. Code above can be used straight upto KitKat. On Lollipop, android: will be need if this style is placed in res/values-21/styles.xml. And the parent theme in that case would be Theme.Material.Light

Comment: [Styling the Action Bar](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it programmatically:

To Hide the status bar:
        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);

To hide the action bar:
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.hide();

More info here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html
https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status.html